# Marker won't display on the map. What can I do to solve this?

Tags: reactjs

What should I do? I've tried to create a custom Marker using an icon but it won't display on the map. Also, I tried to put a simple Marker but again...no results.
In the last part, I was trying to display just 3 Markers on the map.

```
 import React, {Component} from "react";
    import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
    import './LocMap.css'
    import axios from "axios";
    import "./marker.png"
    
    
    const Marker = (e) => {
        if (e.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <img src={require("./marker.png")} alt={"marker"}/>
    
                </div>
            );
        } else
            return (<div/>);
    };
    
    const props = {
        center: {
            lat: 46.150835,
            lng: 24.333331,
        },
        zoom: 14
    };
    
    
    class LocMap extends Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
    
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                users: [],
                startDate: "",
                endDate: "",
                locations: [],
    
            };
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
    
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/users/getAll')
                .then(res => {
    
                    const data = res.data
                    console.log(data)
                    this.setState({users: data})
    
    
                })
                .catch(
                    err => {
                        console.log(err)
    
                    }
                )
    
        }
    
        handleSubmit = async e => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
    
            const data = {
                startDate: this.startDate,
                endDate: this.endDate
            }
            console.log(data.startDate)
            console.log(data.endDate)
    
    
            await axios.get("http://localhost:8080" + "/location/filter?startDate=" + data.startDate + "&endDate=" + data.endDate)
                .then(
                    res => {
                        const data = res.data
                        this.setState({locations: data})
                     
    
                    })
                .catch(
                    err => {
                        console.log(err)
    
                    }
                )
    
    
        };
    
    
        render() {
            return (
    
                <div className='Location'>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="select-container">
                            <select>
                                {
                                    this.state.users.map(item => (
                                        <option key={item.id} value={item.email}>
                                            {item.email}
                                        </option>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div id='startdate'>
                            <label>Start date</label>
                            <input type="text" format="MM/DD/YYYY" name='startDate' id='a1' placeholder="Start Date"
                                   onChange={e => this.startDate = e.target.value}/>
                        </div>
    
                        <div id='enddate'>
                            <label>End date</label>
                            <input type="text" format="MM/DD/YYYY" name='endDate' id='a2' placeholder="End Date"
                                   onChange={e => this.endDate = e.target.value}/>
                        </div>
    
                        <button type="submit" name="search" id="search">Search</button>
    
                    </form>
    
    
                    <div id="mapArea">
                        <GoogleMapReact
                            defaultCenter={props.center}
                            defaultZoom={props.zoom}
                        >
                            {this.state.locations.length > 0 ? (
                                <Marker
                                    lat={this.state.locations[0].latitude}
                                    lng={this.state.locations[0].longitude}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <Marker
                                    lat={0}
                                    lng={0}
                                />
                            )}
                            {this.state.locations.length > 1 ? (
                                <Marker
                                    lat={this.state.locations[1].latitude}
                                    lng={this.state.locations[1].longitude}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <Marker/>
                            )}
                            {this.state.locations.length > 2 ? (
                                <Marker
                                    lat={this.state.locations.latitude}
                                    lng={this.state.locations.longitude}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <Marker/>
                            )}
    
    
                        </GoogleMapReact>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            );
        }
    
    }
    
    export default LocMap;
```

I apologize for incorectly formatting the code. It's my first post here.

Comment: Hello, can you format properly the code and display all the file please. It is pretty hard to read it actually

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. It's the first time when I'm posting here